# Fetch registered user in XAMPP for ios

Tags: ios, ios7, xampp, chat

I am working on the XAMPP in one of the IOS project. 
where i want to fetch all the registered users..

Below is the code which i had used:-

```
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
```

NSXMLElement *query = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='all users'/>" error:&error];

XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"DOMAIN"]

[appDel_friends.xmppStream sendElement:iq];

I got an Error error code 404 item not found.

Request:

```
SEND: <iq type="get" to="ios.ioschat.com" id="44BF120A-83F5-4AB8-85AD-006D752B716E"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" node="all users"/></iq>
```

Responce:-

```
 RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="44BF120A-83F5-4AB8-85AD-006D752B716E" from="ios.ioschat.com" to="user928@ios.ioschat.com/1661f8e6"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" node="all users"/><error code="404" type="cancel"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in view did load set this

```
 [defaults setObject:@"your mid" forKey:@"kXMPPmyJID"];
   [defaults setObject:@"your password" forKey:@"kXMPPmyPassword"];
    [defaults synchronize];

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController == nil)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self appDelegate ] managedObjectContext_roster];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sectionNum" ascending:YES];
        NSSortDescriptor *sd2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayName" ascending:YES];

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, sd2, nil];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                       managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionNum"
                                                                                  cacheName:nil];
        [fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
        {
            DDLogError(@"Error performing fetch: %@", error);
        }

    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}

- (void)configurePhotoForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell user:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)user
{
    // Our xmppRosterStorage will cache photos as they arrive from the xmppvCardAvatarModule.
    // We only need to ask the avatar module for a photo, if the roster doesn't have it.

    if (user.photo != nil)
    {
        //cell.imageView.image = user.photo;
        UIImageView *imgview =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 45, 45)];
        imgview.image =user.photo;
        [cell addSubview:imgview];
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *photoData = [[[self appDelegate ] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid];

        UIImageView *imgview =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 45, 45)];
        if (photoData != nil)
            imgview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
        else
            imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPerson"];

        [cell addSubview:imgview];

    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)sender titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

    if (sectionIndex < [sections count])
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];

        int section = [sectionInfo.name intValue];
        switch (section)
        {
            case 0  : return @"Available";
            case 1  : return @"Away";
            default : return @"Offline";
        }
    }

    return @"";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   /* if(frnds.count>0)
    {
        return frnds.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    */
    NSArray *sections = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections];

    if (section < [sections count])
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:section];
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
    }

    return 0;

}

/*-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}*/


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
/*  //  [cell.accessoryType ] =[UIColor colorWithRed:203.0/255.0f green:22.0/255.0f blue:110.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    if(frnds.count>0)
    {
        UILabel *namelbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,15,200,30)];
        namelbl.text = [[frnds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"first_name"] ;
        namelbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [namelbl setMinimumFontSize:8];
        namelbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:203.0/255.0f green:22.0/255.0f blue:110.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        namelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
       // [namelbl setNumberOfLines:2];
        [cell addSubview:namelbl];
        [namelbl release];
    }
    */

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *namelbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,15,200,30)];
    namelbl.text = user.displayName;
    namelbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    [namelbl setMinimumFontSize:8];
    namelbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:203.0/255.0f green:22.0/255.0f blue:110.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];
    namelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    // [namelbl setNumberOfLines:2];
    [cell addSubview:namelbl];
    [namelbl release];

    [self configurePhotoForCell:cell user:user];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return cell;
}
- (XMPPStream *)xmppStream {
    return [[self appDelegate ] xmppStream];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"user man %@",user.jidStr);



}
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return 50;

}
```